# Tokenizing dutch words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

Reading [this](https://ilmoirfan.com/multi-lingual-support-in-nltk-for-sentence-tokenization/) article I found out that I can use a Dutch sentence tokenizer as follows:

```
nltk.download('punkt')
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/dutch.pickle')
tokernizer.tokenize('Ik liep naar huis. Dat deed ik gisteren')
```

However is there a way of using a dutch word tokenizer? The English one (the default 'punkt') seems to work but I am guessing that it could go wrong at some point.

Comment: What are cases where Dutch is tokenized differently from English?

Comment: @tripleee I would not know. I am making an assumption here as there seems to be a special model  for sentence tokenization as well from what I am getting from the example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=word_tokenize#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize) :

```
nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(text, language='english', preserve_line=False)
```

It seem like you can specify the language:

```
nltk.word_tokenize('Ik liep naar huis. Dat deed ik gisteren', language='dutch')
```

Also beware, 'punkt' is a sentence tokenizer, it will segment a document in sentences. The `nltk.word_tokenize` executes punt and then a word segmenter.

Alternatively you can check [spacy](https://spacy.io/models).